# not correctly display results in a textarea Ruby + Sinatra + Haml

Tags: ruby, sinatra, textarea, haml, return-value

```
#encoding:utf-8
#! /usr/local/bin/ruby

require "sinatra"
require "haml"

Encoding.default_internal = Encoding.default_external = "UTF-8"

get "/*" do
  haml :index
end

post '/' do
  @track_in = params[:track_in]
  @track_out = out(@track_in)
  haml :index
end

def out(trackin)
  if trackin != nil
    track = trackin.lines.to_a
    for i in 0 .. track.size
      if track[i] != nil
        tr = track[i].chomp.split(/\s\t/)
        n,r,k = tr[0],tr[1],tr[2]
        t = "#{n}.#{k}(#{r})" if k != nil
        t = "#{n}.#{r}" if k == nil or track[i] == /([0-9]{2})\s\t(.+)\r/
        puts "#{t}\n"
      end
    end
  end
end

__END__

@@ index

!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta#_moz_html_fragment/
    %title
  %body
    #main_wrapper
      #page
        #editing_header
        .clear
        #preview{style: "border: 5px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 1em 0pt; padding: 5px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 50%; display: none; width: 75%; -moz-background-clip: -moz-initial; -moz-background-origin: -moz-initial; -moz-background-inline-policy: -moz-initial;"}
        %form#form{action: "", method: "post"}
          %table{border: "0", cellpadding: "0", cellspacing: "0", style: "width: 0:px;"}
            %thead
            %tbody
            %input{name: "Submit", type: "submit"}/
          %textarea#track_in{cols: "100", rows: "15", name: "track_in"}= @track_in
          %textarea#track_out{cols: "100", rows: "15", name: "track_out"}= @track_out
```

output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhplC.jpg
desired result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0xtJ.jpg

to convert the tracklist. place the point in the right places, bracketed text and in a specific order

Help me please

Comment: text for the test (in the screenshots) is available here http://www.jame-world.com/us/database-items-35208-beautiful-deformity-limited-edition-.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't return proper result(s) from `out` method. Just try this:

```
def out(trackin)
  res = []
  if trackin != nil
    track = trackin.lines.to_a
    for i in 0 .. track.size
      if track[i] != nil
        tr = track[i].chomp.split(/\s\t/)
        n,r,k = tr[0],tr[1],tr[2]
        t = "#{n}.#{k}(#{r})" if k != nil
        t = "#{n}.#{r}" if k == nil or track[i] == /([0-9]{2})\s\t(.+)\r/
#       puts "#{t}\n"
        res << "#{t}\n"
      end
    end
  end
  res.join
end
```

Now your `out` returns string of desired result. Method collects strings into array `res` and finally joins all lines into one string which you should see in the textbox.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,надеюсь в дальнейшем я буду учиться внимательнее

Comment: No problems. Good luck ;)